# android -BaseAdapter doesn't add new items to listView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I don't know why my listView doesn't add new items .

this is the code :

```
   ListAdapter ladap;

    private class GetContacts AsyncTask<Void, Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + page, Spots_tab1_json.GET);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataC = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = new String(c.getString("id").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    String dates = new String(c.getString("dates").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    String price = new String(c.getString("gheymat").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("dates", dates);
                    contact.put("price", price);
                    dataC.add(contact);
                }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                goterr = true;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                goterr = true;
            }
        } else {
            goterr = true;
        }
        return dataC;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
            if(ladap==null){
                ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,result);
                lv.setAdapter(ladap);
            }else{
                ladap.addAll(result);
                ladap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    }
}


    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    public ListAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = (Activity) activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        Log.v("this",result.size()+" resultsize");
        this.list = result;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title,price;
        ImageView img ; 
        //RelativeLayout rl; 
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            item = contactList.get(position);
            holder.price.setText(item.get("price"));
        return convertView;
    }
    }
```

with help of friends ,I solve my last problem , the new problem is this , The adapter doesn't update so it doesn't add new rows  to ListView. I logged and I've 30 new items in the baseAdapter here :

```
public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            Log.v("this",result.size()+" resultsize");
            this.list = result;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

but it's not adding to listView.

could you help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: The first line in the exceptions are telling you exactly what is wrong. You're modifying the lists' data set. It looks to me like you're creating brand new adapters on the fly, instead of using one you've created previously.

Comment: I think you have declare adapter object outside and check onPostExecute if is null then cerate new instance othere wise just pass your new data in adapter updateList method but you have change code in updateList method also where you cant set this.list == list instead of this check if list is null then create new instance of list and add all data to list like : list.addAll().

Comment: Could you post your entire activity? something doesn't make sense

Comment: @LokiSinclair thanks for reply , I update my code but still get this error . Could you do me a favor and  have a look at my new code . Maybe you can help me to solve this bothering problem . Thanks

Comment: @HareshChhelana  thanks for reply , I update my code but still get this error . Could you do me a favor and  have a look at my new code . Maybe you can help me to solve this bothering problem . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have used contactList ArrayList to showing ListView item and you will update data to contactList in doinBackground() which run another thread not in ui thread so you can not update ui data from out ui therad hence you have to take local ArrayList for doInBackground() and pass new or updated data to onPostExecute() which update this data to ui thread.

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + page, Spots_tab1_json.GET);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = new String(c.getString("id").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    String dates = new String(c.getString("dates").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    String price = new String(c.getString("gheymat").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("dates", dates);
                    contact.put("price", price);
                    data.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(ladap==null){
            ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,result);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
        }else{
            ladap.addAll(result);
            ladap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for you reply ,I change my code to what you said ( I update my question with new codes ) .  I think with your help the last problem is solve but there is a new problem , the listview doesn't update after I calling ladap.addAll(result);  I logged and I had 30 new items but it doesn't add new items to listView . Could you help me about this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
 public void updateList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
             this.list = list;
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

this is wrong too

```
if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
            ListAdapter ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
            ladap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //ladap.updateList(contactList);
    }
```

What you can do is instead of creating a new Adapter, add data to your previous adapter that you have created above

```
ListAdapter ladap
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,I remove the first part of code you said , the second part , you said it's wrong , What should I replace instead?

Comment: add it to your adapter and then after you are done just notify your adapter about data set changed or data set invalidated :)

Comment: Once you have set the adapter, keep going with the same adapter, extend your Adapter with ArrayAdapter rather than BaseAdapter.

Comment: [see this 2.3. ListView example with ArrayAdapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: thanks for reply , I update my code but still get this error . Could you do me a favor and  have a look at my new code . Maybe you can help me to solve this bothering problem . Thanks

Comment: Dear first you have to create a adapter, provide it with a list of data and instead of doing this on your `postExecute` method, just add it to your list that you have already provided in your `postExecute`. This code is wrong ` ladap=new `ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,result);`
               ` lv.setAdapter(ladap);`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
        ListAdapter ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
        lv.setAdapter(ladap);
        ladap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //ladap.updateList(contactList);
}
```

is wrong.

It should be

```
if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
        ladap.addAll(contactList);
        ladap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You should define your adapter only once and update the values in it accordingly. [You can use various constructors to suit your requirements.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

---------------------EDITED---------------------

```
if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
            if(ladap==null){
                ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                lv.setAdapter(ladap);
                ladap.addAll(contactList);

            }else{
                ladap.addAll(contactList);
}

    }

public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList) {
thislist.clear();       
 this.list = contactList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply , I update my code but still get this error . Could you do me a favor and have a look at my new code . Maybe you can help me to solve this bothering problem . Thanks

Comment: thislist.clear();  clears the data , I mean , after implementing this line, listview is empty and nothing retrieve .

Comment: protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) returns nothing. To get the data, you need to return from the doInBackground() method. And then update the contact listview using that data. the problem is the ArrayList that bound to Adapter is changed in the Background thread. Your adapter is actually modified from a background thread, exactly as the exception suggested. The solution is moving it to UI thread.Check @Haresh Chhelana answer.

Comment: thanks for reply ,,I change my code to what you said ( I update my question with new codes ) . I think the last problem is solve but there is a new problem , the listview doesn't update after I calling ladap.addAll(result); I logged and I had 30 new items but it doesn't add new items to listView . Could you help me about this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if you want to create an adapter ONLY once then fine, do it when the asyc task ends, otherwise make it a member and initiate it in an onCreate or something like that.

Technically if you replace all the content of the list, then your approach is fine, replace the ArrayList, but don't forget to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

BUT if you only change some of the content of the list e.g. you add new elements or remove elements, then you should perform these changes on the original ArrayList, and then call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

NOTE, all calls to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() should be done on UI Thread.

Also, from what I see, if this is the exact code you are running you should not get this error, it seemed like the error is generated from another place.

Comment: thanks for reply , I update my code but still get this error . Could you do me a favor and  have a look at my new code . Maybe you can help me to solve this bothering problem . Thanks

Comment: try to create the adapter in the Activity onCreate e.g. these lines:        ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,result);
                lv.setAdapter(ladap);

Comment: Also it might be something related to AsyncTask and memory leaks, but I can't say for sure without full debug capabilities