# How to append records in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have implemented list view from following link.

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

**Requirement**

Now i want to add load more button below list and when user will click on button then more record will append to list view.

**Problem**

For this i have explored stack overflow and other websites and seen examples but i could not got anything relevant to solution of my problem because my knowledge is limited in android as i just started few days ago.

so can you please provide me guidance or any reference link or any example code according to code i have done so that i can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Following code demanded by Little Child

```
public static void addNewData(ArrayList<SearchResults> jobs) {
    SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setJobTitle("Test job1");
    sr1.setJobPostedDate("2014-12-13");
    sr1.setJobSkills("php,mysql");
    jobs.add(sr1);

    sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setJobTitle("Test job2");
    sr1.setJobPostedDate("2014-12-13");
    sr1.setJobSkills("php,mysql");
    jobs.add(sr1);

    sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setJobTitle("Test job3");
    sr1.setJobPostedDate("2014-12-13");
    sr1.setJobSkills("php,mysql");
    jobs.add(sr1);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Add items to your provider (Array, list etc...)  refresh your adapter and bind to your listview

Comment: try this link http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602037/android-baseadapter-doesnt-add-new-items-to-listview/26797517#26797517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.

You have some backing data that the `ListView` displays via an adapter. Whenever the user click the "Load More" button, load some more data and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

That's it.

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON I know that feeling! Been there! :D

Comment: But question is how to add data second time in adapter? because i want to append records.

Comment: @employeegts It depends on *how* the data is stored in the adapter. If it is in an `ArrayList`, it is just a matter of calling `add()`.

Comment: I have used exactly same as http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

Comment: So, add a new method to the `MyCustomBaseAdapter` class so that you  can add more data to the underlying `ArrayList`. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Here i don't have object of adapter so how to call notifyDataSetChanged() in this case

Comment: you can call it inside the adapter itself from the method where you add more data to the `ArrayList`